# how to restart dag and tasks in airflow even they were succeed.

Tags: task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I was trying to restart the whole dag and tasks even they succeeded.

I made a dag and run an instance of dag. there are 5 tasks this day. the first four tasks were succeeded but the last task was failed. so I made a change on these tasks. I want these 5 tasks can re-run again. but the first four tasks never get rerun. airflow do some unwanted thing that directly to run the last task and pretended it has rerun the first four tasks. even i did som many changed in the first four tasks. 
Is there anyone can help me?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to clear the DAG run: Click on the top green circle and click on the Clear button, then confirm clearing the tasks.